# Android SharedPreferences remove first entry regardless the key

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I need to remove first entry of SharedPreferences in my Android app

I know I can use `remove("key")` but in this case I don't know the key, need it to be dynamic

The reason is that I'm storing array with 10-value capacity. When SharedPreferences contains 10 instances, it removes the first and adds new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would store your preference as a single entry as a json list or a simple comma separated list. Thereby it is much easier to work with.

For JSON you can use the gson library (part of android 3.0+) or download it from: http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/